# Jekyll is generating random characters in my blog post URLs

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm working on building a site using Jekyll and GitHub Pages. I've gotten it down for the most part, but there's an odd issue I can't seem to figure out.

My blog post pages that are generated by Jekyll have a set of seemingly random characters generated at the end of the URL after the page loads. Here's an example:

http://www.jenniferaldoretta.com/2014/01/12/welcome-to-my-website/

The link works but is changed to http://www.jenniferaldoretta.com/2014/01/12/welcome-to-my-website/#.UtQZa2RDt8U after the page finishes loading.

Is this something that is typical for Jekyll or is there something I'm doing wrong? This issue started only after I integrated my site with Jekyll. I'm wondering if anyone has ideas on what might be causing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use actual links to illustrate your issue, because they won't _work_ in the future if you fix it. You still can use code formatting to do this. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've enabled address bar tracking `{"data_track_addressbar":true}` which appends those parameters to your URL. They're there so that we can collect analytics when someone copies the URL out of the address bar instead of going through the addthis sharing tool. It shouldn't affect people linking to your site and can provide insight into what content is the most popular on your site.

If they're not wanted or are causing issues, you're free to disable address bark sharing tracking. Just adjust your addthis_config variable in your site like this:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like social-buttons" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet social-buttons"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-52ceee943bc45eff"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

More information about address bar sharing analytics is available here: http://www.addthis.com/help/address-bar-sharing-analytics